# How send application/x-www-form-urlencoded params to a RestServer with JMeter?

Tags: rest, mime-types, jmeter, form-data

I developed a rest server, and I put it to run in localhost, and I'm trying to perform tests with JMeter, sending requests posts and gets (depends of called method).

I already send to Rest server and got result with JMeter in simple post requests, get requests, sending files with post, and sending a Json with post.

But I don't know how to send a `Form-UrlEncoded` object to server. My Rest server consumes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and I need to send 3 String parameters.

There's some way to set the `MimeType` for every parameter and perform the test ?

I'm using Jmeter 2.7

- **[Update]**

I solved this by disabling the option:

```
use multipart/form-data for post
```

And enabling:

```
redirect automatically
```

Instead of:

```
follow redirect
```

The parameters I put normally in the table "Send parameters with the Request" with each respective names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to save your test using [BadBoy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) or [JMeter Proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) to see what your application actually sends?

To see what happens under the hood you can also use `FireBug` if you're using FireFox or `Ctrl+Shift+i` if you're on Chrome.

Comment: also F12 on any current browser will show you the Network chatter.

Answer (score 29):

For sending form parameters as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, add a header parameter Content-Type with value application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

The following steps is aplicable for Jmeter 2.3.4

1. Add a HTTP Header Manager under your http Request.
2. Add new parameter to HTTP Header Manager with name Content-Type and value application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
3. Uncheck "Use multipart/form-data for HTTP POST" of HTTP request.
4. Uncheck "Encode?" of each request parameter(not necessary).
5. kept "Content Encode:" text box of HTTP request as empty.

   **This won't work for PUT request.**
   For put request add parameters as path parameter and set Content-Type header then Jmeter will do by itself.

Comment: This worked very well. Thanks for sharing these steps.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the solution for HTTP POST with x-www-form-urlencoded testing with jmeter. You just folllow like these.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Go to Thread Group -> Add listener -> Views Result in table, View result Tree. To see the process of responding.

Answer (score 0):

IllegalCharsetNameException will go immediately only after you will add the required content-type in HTTP Header Manager for HTTP request .

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

followed exact steps mentioned i still see an exception thrown

Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.checkName(Charset.java:315)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup2(Charset.java:484)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Charset.java:464)
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:528)
    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(ContentType.java:210)
    at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.<init>(StringEntity.java:116)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sendPostData(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1340)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.handleMethod(HTTPHC4Impl.java:592)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:409)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1166)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1155)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It does work after i have upgraded from JMeter 3.1 to 3.2

Comment: This is not an answer to the question at hand. Either take this to chat or post a new question referring to this one.

Comment: It's an answer ain't it