# apache jmeter post with formurlencoded data request fails

Tags: jmeter

my request type is as shown below :

[image]

[image]

here my request is turning into bad request. So how can i make it successful request ?

Comment: We don't know what your API expects or doesn't expect. Maybe it's expecting another parameter? Maybe in some other format? Check the response data - might give you some hints.

Comment: Content-Type needed for the api is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: https goes to Protocol, mywebsite.com goes to server name or IP, the request looks much more like GET than POST (check this out twice). Beyond this trivial, elementary things, no one (except you) knows ain't nothing about the system under test - how do you expect us people to help?

Comment: @YuriG I have already followed the question here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250555/how-to-send-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-params-to-a-restserver-with-jmeter` and then when it did not worked , i asked.

Comment: Sorry, did you read what I was saying? You misconfigured your request, that's what your picture is revealing right away. Solve this first.

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 400 explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400):

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server could not understand the request due to invalid syntax.
>
> ```
> The client should not repeat this request without modification.
> ```

So most probably you're sending the request in the wrong way, i.e. URL or parameters are incorrect or something is missing.

Looking into the request nature, it seems you want to log in somewhere. Real users which use real browsers cannot login in a single request, in the absolute majority of cases it looks like:

1. Open login page (normally [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request)
2. Perform login (normally [HTTP POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request)

So my expectation is that you should have at least 2 requests in your scenario.

With regards to "fixing" the request - you need to make it look like in a real browser. I have no idea where did you get URL, method and parameters, but you should take a closer look there and check for mismatches. Identical requests must produce identical results so if you [make your JMeter request to look like the request in the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) - it should automatically fix your issue.

At last but not the least: are you aware of JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) it is a proxy server which can intercept the traffic between the browser and the system under test and convert it to [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

Answer (score 0):

People who seek for the answer this might be helpful. Add HTTP Header Manager sampler as a child for HTTP Request sampler and add 'Content-Type' as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. This will resolve the issue.
[HTTP Header Manager sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4MSI.png)